# Tigase refuses Tsung

Tags: xmpp, tsung, tigase

I set up a tigase(5.1.5) server, and succeed to register, login and chat using Spark. But strangely I failed to use tsung(1.5.0) to perform loading test.

I use the jabber_registrer.xml as tsung script. The tsung log shows the error, it seems that tigase refuses the connection from tsung:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 28-Jun-2013::02:39:32 ===
   ts_client:(4:<0.6960.0>) connection close while sending message !

=INFO REPORT==== 28-Jun-2013::02:39:32 ===
   ts_client:(5:<0.6960.0>) Server must have closed connection upon us, waiting 10 msec
```

My tigase.conf:

```
ENC="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8"
DRV="-Djdbc.drivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
GC="-XX:+UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:ParallelCMSThreads=8 -XX:-ReduceInitialCardMarks"
EX="-XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -XX:+UseNUMA"
JAVA_HOME="${JAVA_HOME}"
CLASSPATH=""
JAVA_OPTIONS="${GC} ${EX} ${ENC} ${DRV} -server -Xms100M -Xmx2000M -XX:PermSize=32m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=128m "
TIGASE_CONFIG="etc/tigase.xml"
TIGASE_OPTIONS=" --property-file etc/init.properties --test "
```

My init.properties:

```
config-type=--gen-config-def
--admins=admin@$xmppserver.com
--virt-hosts = www.xmppserver.com
--monitoring=jmx:9050,http:9080,snmp:9060
--auth-db=tigase-auth
--user-db=mysql
--user-db-uri=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/tigasedb?user=root&password=111111&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
--user-repo-pool-size=12
```

I use db-create-mysql.sh to set up my database:

```
#scripts/db-create-mysql.sh tigase_user tigase_passwd tigasedb root 111111 localhost
```

My first goal is to create some users in tigase by tsung, but I got this error and can not create any user at all.
I ran tsung on server itself, then on a client PC, both get the same error. Is there anyone has the same problem? Thanks for any answer!

Comment: "jabber_registrer.xml ". Let's see it. Make sure you set only 2 or 3 users to register via tsung so you can follow the logs more easily. Add this line to init.properties:  "--debug = server,xmpp.impl,db"   and watch the file logs/tigase.log.0. Paste the relevant output to pastebin or somewhere else and link it here too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks kellogs, it's my bad.
The problem is in the script of tsung. In  section, the "domain" value must be the same as "virt-hosts" value in etc/init.properties of tigase.
And why tigase said "Address already in use" is because it was once aborted abnormally, kill the jvm process manually can resolve this.